# Node update a specific sub package

Tags: node.js, npm

I am using `react-chat-widget` in one of my project which has `markdown-it` version 8.4.1 as dependency. markdown-it@v8.4.1 has some CVEs so we wanted to update it to the latest.

react-chat-widget has not been updated since long and I am avoiding forking and creating a PR against it.

```
├─┬react-chat-widget@^3.1.4:
  ├─markdown-it "^8.4.1"
```